# Datatables 1.10 bSelectedOnly equivalent

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to find the equivalent of bSelectedOnly in the new version of Datatables 1.10.
I only want to print rows that the user has selected, or print all rows if they havn't selected any.

```
"tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "/Datatables-1.10.0/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf", //Add buttons for saving table data in these formats
    "sRowSelect": "os",  //allow user to select multiple rows in the table
    "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "print",
                "bSelectedOnly": "true",

            },
            {
                "sExtends": "select_none",
            },

        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hasn't changed ([see docs](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options)). But you have an error in your code. Instead of

```
"bSelectedOnly": "true",
```

it should be

```
"bSelectedOnly": true,
```

Also, `bSelectedOnly` is not available as a print option. It is only available as a flash button option. See [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options#Flash-button-options). That is the actual reason why what you're trying to do will not work :)

Comment: Doh! Thank you, I missed that. However, it still doesn't work. I assume it's not setup to work with the print function?